# iOS get notified when microphone can be accessed

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, avaudiosession

I would like my app to be notified when microphone interruption has ended before i start recording.

say for example my application is trying to start recording from background and during this time if any other applications like skype is accessing microphone and i shouldn't do. so i want to start register/observe for interruption so that when skype call ended, my app should be notified.

I can able to achieve only when app is recording and interruption began . i will be notified when interruption ended not on while about to start recording . 
please help .

I tried to register using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];

// observe the interruption begin / end
- (void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType interruptionType = [notification.userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptions interruptionOption = [notification.userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    NSLog(@"interruptionType:%lu",(unsigned long)interruptionType);

    switch (interruptionType) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
            NSLog(@"interruption began");
            break;
        }
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
            NSLog(@"interruption ended");
             break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```